# How i can create a java object in php and use it in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

i need to create a object at a php page and send it as a response by a ajax call to use in in the response page as a javascript object.

This kind of object i need to create an pass through.

```
var areaChartData = {
            labels  : ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
            datasets: [
              {
                label               : 'Electronics',
                fillColor           : 'rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)',
                strokeColor         : 'rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)',
                pointColor          : 'rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)',
                pointStrokeColor    : '#c1c7d1',
                pointHighlightFill  : '#fff',
                pointHighlightStroke: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
                data                : [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
              },
              {
                label               : 'Digital Goods',
                fillColor           : 'rgba(60,141,188,0.9)',
                strokeColor         : 'rgba(60,141,188,0.8)',
                pointColor          : '#3b8bba',
                pointStrokeColor    : 'rgba(60,141,188,1)',
                pointHighlightFill  : '#fff',
                pointHighlightStroke: 'rgba(60,141,188,1)',
                data                : [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
              }
            ]
          }
```

How i can do it? Is it possible?

Comment: Sure, it's possible. Create object in PHP and than use `json_encode`.

Comment: Related : [How do I pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-do-i-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Three steps to doing this:

1. Create the object as a PHP [associative array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) containing a mix of associative arrays and plain arrays.
2. Send it to the browser as JSON via [`json_encode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).
3. On the browser, parse the response from JSON (either as part of receiving it — the [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch) API will parse JSON for you, as will axios — or parse the text of the response manually via [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)).

For example:

```php
<?php
$example = array(
    "x" => [1, 2, 3],
    "y" => ["a", "b", "c"],
    "z" => array(
        "nested" => 42,
        "stuff" => [4, 5, 6]
    ),
);
echo json_encode($example);
```

That will output this JSON (formatting added):

```json
{
    "x": [1, 2, 3],
    "y": ["a", "b", "c"],
    "z": {
        "nested": 42,
        "stuff": [4, 5, 6]
    }
}
```

...which can be parsed into a JavaScript object tree:

```js
const json = `{
    "x": [1, 2, 3],
    "y": ["a", "b", "c"],
    "z": {
        "nested": 42,
        "stuff": [4, 5, 6]
    }
}`;
const obj = JSON.parse(json);
console.log(obj.x[0]); // 1
console.log(obj);
```